# ERROR: Cron Job ngenius_order_update has an error: Incorrect theme identification key Magento 2.4

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

We have a commerce cloud store and we are using ngenius payment gateway it's throwing a log error in the log file.

```
[2023-04-26T02:00:22.001261+00:00] report.ERROR: Cron Job ngenius_order_update has an error: Incorrect theme identification key.
```

Kindly help us to fix this issue.